# Is there a way to estimate my PHP server upload speed?

Tags: php, performance, upload

I have some shared PHP hostings and I would like to estimate the server upload speed. I want it to do this on its own without a user or a system trying to download a file to get the php server upload speed. I mean, something like a speedtest but done by the php server towards an external service, so I can retrieve the upload speed. Hope this it's clear enough.

PS. they are shared hosting so I cannot install anything at system level.

Comment: Would something like the Speedtest Web SDK work? I can also find a fast.com npm library.

Comment: Mmm, It is a shared php hosting so I can basically only do something with php code. fast.com library seems to interact with the user connnection speed.